# How to make ActionBar Slide with the Drawer

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I have created a drawer Layout using ActionBarSherlock and the support library. Does anyone know if its possible or how to make the Actionbar Slide with the menu so that it's not static?

Comment: Note that this goes against [the Android design guidelines for navigation drawers](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use the [SlidingMenu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) library by jfeinstein10. Its really useful and provides a lot more functionality than the default android one. Plus, you can enabled it really easy and attach the same drawer to many different activities.

Here is a quick tutorial:

```
    SlidingMenu <menu_name> = new SlidingMenu(this);
    <menu_name>.setMode(SlidingMenu.RIGHT);
    <menu_name>.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_MARGIN);
    <menu_name>.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
    <menu_name>.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadowright);
    <menu_name>.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
    <menu_name>.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
    <menu_name>.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_WINDOW);
    <menu_name>.setMenu(<layout_for_drawer>);
```

P.S you can get the dimens and drawables from his example activity.